# how to remove bytes from zip file in java?

Tags: java, zip

I made a project to encrypt a file by converting it to a zip file, then adding an array of bytes to it.
When clicking on the file after addition, it returns "damaged file".

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class TestByteSyt {  
byte[] data;
public void choos(String path){
try{
data=getBytesContent(path);}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.print("there is problem");
  }   
}
  public  byte[] getBytesContent(String path){
    byte[] filedata = null;
    try{
      File file = new File(path);
      filedata = new byte[(int)file.length()];
      FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
      FileOutputStream output= new FileOutputStream(file);
      //input.read(filedata);
      String pass="the password is sobhi saede";
      byte[] b=pass.getBytes();
       System.out.print(b);
       output.write(b);
       input.close();
       output.close();
        // System.out.print( file.delete());
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
    {System.out.print("no file ");}
    return filedata;
  }}
```

How to remove the added bytes from the zip file to make it work again?

Comment: Your approach really doesn't "encrypt" the data. All it does is break it in an entirely reversible way. Do *not* think that this gives you any security. Additionally, it's not clear why you're then overwriting the original file using `BufferedWriter`...

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to encrypt your zip files, check out [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/).

Comment: ok but i try to make extintion windows cant read it to make new extintion